# Apply an aspect to only methods that have a specific attribute

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I'm trying to set up a PostSharp aspect `RunOutOfProcessAttribute` so that it applies to:

1. all public methods
2. any method marked with the `DoSpecialFunctionAttribute`, regardless of member accessibility (public/protected/private/whatever).

So far, my `RunOutOfProcessAttribute` is defined thusly:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class RunOutOfProcessAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `MulticastAttributeUsageAttribute` already in place should fulfil criterion 1 above, but I've got no idea how to fulfil criterion 2, without simply duplicating the behaviour of the existing aspect into a new attribute.

How would I get this aspect to apply to any method marked with the `DoSpecialFunctionAttribute`, regardless of member accessibility (public/protected/private/whatever)?

Comment: im confused as to why this is required. If you already are going to have a `DoSpecialFunctionAttribute` why not just include the function to do this in that attribute? rather than creating yet ANOTHER aspect.

Comment: I want to be able to put `RunOutOfProcessAttribute` on a class, as it more defines a class behaviour than a method behaviour. `RunOutOfProcessAttribute` should operate on *all* public class methods in addition to any protected one marked with `DoSpecialFunctionAttribute`. `DoSpecialFunctionAttribute` will not be an aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution:

- Target all methods with `[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method)]`
- Override `CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)`. Set up the return values such that `CompileTimeValidate` returns `true` on appropriate targets, `false` on targets to silently ignore, and throws an exception when the user should be alerted that Aspect usage is inappropriate (this is detailed in the [PostSharp documentation](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/M_PostSharp_Extensibility_IValidableAnnotation_CompileTimeValidate.htm)).

In code:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method)]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class RunOutOfProcessAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    protected static bool IsOutOfProcess;

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
    {
        if (method.DeclaringType.GetInterface("IDisposable") == null)
            throw new InvalidAnnotationException("Class must implement IDisposable " + method.DeclaringType);

        if (!method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.Public) && //if method is not public
            !MethodMarkedWith(method,typeof(InitializerAttribute))) //method is not initialiser
            return false; //silently ignore.

        return true;
    }
}
```